# angular get document id from firestore when querying on other condition

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the document id from a fireStore query that isn't looking for the id:

e.g.

```
getGalleryByPage(url: string) {
    return this.db.collection('content', ref => ref.where('slug', '==', url)).snapshotChanges();
  }

this.pageUrl = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('pageUrl');
const array = this.getGalleryByPage(this.pageUrl).subscribe(res => {
  const myArray = [];
    res.forEach((doc) => {
     const y = doc.payload.doc.data();
     console.log('id' + y);
    });
  });
```

But the doc id isn't showing up in the `console.log`, just the data retrieved within the document itself. What do I need to do to retrieve the id other than log the id within the data as well?

Answer (score 3):

The `data()` method of a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) returns an object containing the document's data. To add document's ID in the object, try:

```
const array = this.getGalleryByPage(this.pageUrl).subscribe(res => {
  const myArray = [];
  res.forEach((doc) => {
      const y = {
        id: doc.payload.doc.id,
        ...doc.payload.doc.data();
        console.log('id' + y);
      });
  });
})
```

Comment: Ugh, don't you hate it when you're so close to the answer but get everything but! Thanks, you're absolutely right.

Comment: @jimbeeer true, Firebase [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js) documentation is crystal clear and useful

Comment: I personally wouldn't call it either of those things, plus it doesn't have code options for Typescript or Angular, but I'm incredibly grateful for your help nonetheless

Comment: @jimbeeer that's the documentation for Firebase JS SDK. I'm not sure about Angular one but it is built on the official SDK so this should be handy.